I cannot acces Solana Tech - Validator
how are you ?
i am trying to get access to the Solana on Discord, but I have no data at all. I cannot send message, actually, it looks like nothing is happening on the discord. Where can I find information about starting a Solana validator  ?
thanks

The Solana core dev discord exists at https://solana.com/discord -- be sure to follow the instructions there
